# Can I sync Persistent volume between two k8s clusters?

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed two k8s clusters and i want that if someone will create pv in first cluster then it should automatically get created in the second cluster. How can i achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

simply speaking you can't: these are separate clusters and each of them has a separate configuration. there is no built-in mechanism of triggering between separate clusters. you would need to build your own program that would be watching both API servers and applying the changes.

I'm guessing however that you probably want to share filesystem data between clusters: if so, then have a look at volume types backed by network/distributed file systems such as [NFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) or [ceph](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#cephfs).

Comment: Yes I am using nfs volume and I have synced nfs path for both the clusters.